# How to install apps from one user to another

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-10

I have a Nexus 10 set up with multiple users. My owner account has a lot of apps that I got from my Humble Library (so not from Google Play). I want to install these apps on one of the other user accounts, but right now I'm on a metered internet connection so I don't want to re-download these apps. Is there a way for me to transfer these non-Google Play apps from the owner user to another user without re-downloading them? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually, with the MultiUser feature, apps are not downloaded again (but rather linked; let's skip technical details here). In your case the trouble is: your apps are not connected to Google Play, so I'm not sure how that would be handled.

However, here's a way you definitely could do so. But it would require you to install one app from Google Play to handle it:

1. Login with your "owner account"
2. Get yourself [AppMonster Free Backup Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager) via Google Play
3. Start the AppMonster, go into its settings, and check/configure the path it stores the backups to. For your goal, it should preferably be in a location accessible for the other users as well.
4. Now "back up" the apps you want to "transfer". You might wish to include *AppMonster* here as well.
5. Login with one of the "target users"
6. Use any file manager to navigate to the *AppMonster* backup directory
7. Now you can simply "start" the `.apk` files, and the installer should pop up.

As the backup directory structure might be a little confusing, you may wish to first install *AppMonster* that way, and use this app itself to install the other apps (after having configured the backup directory again).

Be aware this only handles the apps themselves, not their data.

---

Another variant, including the app data, could be utilizing `adb backup` and `adb restore`. To do this without a computer, you could use [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup). Other than above variant, this creates backup archives (`*.ab`) of your apps, which then could be restored using the very same app. **I've never tried that amongst multiple accounts,** so I cannot guarantee it works. *Helium* is available for Android 4.0 and above; but as you already use the MultiUser feature, this should be no show stopper :)

Note, however, that you would need to install *Helium* also for the accounts you wish to restore to. And again: While I'm pretty sure the *AppMonster* variant will work, **I cannot guarantee that *Helium* works in this context.** But it might be worth a try *if you want to include the data* with your transfer.

Comment: Very slick Izzy, will this also transfer the user data from the app as well?

Comment: No, that could only be done by either a root-app or via `adb backup`. Which brings me to another option, will update my answer.

Comment: I filed a bug report to Google about this, start it to receive updates: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82543